# Are random generated mazes a nuisance?

Tags: game-design, maps, random

To me, random generated maps such as in Diablo2 were often a nuisance.
Many times, you find yourself in a dead end and have to find another way.
However, Diablo2 became a very popular and addictive game.

My Conclusion:

Pros:

- players don't get bored as fast as if you have a static map
- players have to spend more time for levels
- there are more surprises

Cons:

- players (like me) are getting bored. They rather want to get to the boss (e.g. Mephisto) quickly

However, is there a general answer if random generated mazes should still be considered when developing a new game?

Comment: This is really completely opinion based, as there will always be players/developers who find PCG tedious, and there will also always be developers/players who find PCG to be exciting. Additionally, it entirely depends on the game being developed. You might instead ask how you could generate levels that are measurably "fun" (for which there are some interesting solutions).

Comment: you can create mazes without dead ends, discouraging grinders is also a factor

Answer (score 3):

Randomized worlds exist to improve replayability. Any gameplay element can be a nuisance for some people, which is why the focus should be on minimizing the nuisance without damaging the whole gameplay, not removing it completely. You achieve this with mechanics that balance your "possibly annoying" mechanic.

You gave Diablo 2 as an example, so I'll stick to that. Randomized levels mean you get a new level each time, and you don't know anything about it. You don't know where's everything, so in theory you have to re-explore it all the time. However,

> They rather want to get to the boss (e.g. Mephisto) quickly

Blizzard most likely thought of this too. That's why the game has waypoints. Once a waypoint is activated, you can get to it on each newly generated map. This is a very useful mechanic to keep the players with less patience happy: you can go to the closest waypoint to Mephisto, and reduce the search efforts tremendously.

Also, notice how important areas on each map *have noticeable particularities that remain constant across newly generated maps*. That means that even if you're on a new map, you can reduce the search effort by paying attention to these specifics. There may not be 100% excellent examples of this in Diablo (hordes of imps in the same place? chances are you're getting closer to the Cairn Stones), but it's another mechanic that can help with re-exploration.

In the end, if you really want for your game to not annoy any player ever, just don't release it. It's the only way.